# Parent child permission denied

Tags: java, c

I am having a judge which is not running in ubuntu and i think it is written in C and Java
with C program written for parent and child spawning process the code couldnot be run because of following error:

```
 ./client:Permission denied
 ./client:Permission denied
```

how can i solve this problem??

Comment: If you want us to help you, you should provide more information and a context. Currently your question is very chaotic.

Comment: The main problem is the use of the word "judge" -- I can't sort what that means in this context.

Answer (score 2):

```
chmod +x client
```

will add the execute mode to your application

Answer (score 1):

If your program is written in C, then you can try `chmod +x client`, then `./client` to execute it.

If your program is written in Java, then you should use `chmod +x client`, then `java client` to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod 777 ./client
```

This will allow any user to execute.